# Is www.justfly.com is a reliable site to purchase air tickets?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

I found some cheaper offers here but never purchased from this site. Is there anyone who has tried this? Are they reliable?

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search shows that it seems to be a reliable website. https://www.trustpilot.com/review/justfly.com

The only thing that I would make sure of, is that you see all the details of the tickets before you buy. Details that you should note:

- Departure Airport
- Layover/Stops
- Duration of flights and layovers
- Arrival and departure dates

Hope you have safe travels!